# The use of "had to"

Tags: grammar, ambiguity, have-to-versus-must

Does the following phrase mean it must be true?

> This fact had to be true.

Or it must have been true?

I would like a native speaker's opinion on this.

I often hear it used in the second interpretation.

Comment: It depends on the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends entirely upon context. "I knew this fact had to be true, because my wife wouldn't lie to me." Both lines (must be or had to be [or have to be]) generally, but not always, imply that there is some evidence to the contrary of the fact being true. The actual truth (or the author's perception of the truth) can only be clear if you see the line in context.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, "had to be" is somewhat disconnected from factuality.  It can mean that the writer needs the fact to be true, that one hopes it is true, that it had to be true for something else to happen, that circumstances necessitated it to be true because something else is true.  There are probably many more circumstances, but generally, either there is no evidence to back it up (and it refers to an emotional belief or desire) or external evidence proves the fact.  Also, sometimes "facts" are more emotional than actual.

It had to be true...

- the radiation levels were too high for there not to be a leak.  *External evidence proving a fact.  Circumstances required it to be true because something else was true.*
- because his wife would never cheat on him. *Hopes it is true.  Also, using emotional instead of tangible evidence.*
- or all hope would be lost. *Hope it's true, needs the fact to be true.*

It "must have been true" is not disconnected from factuality.  It is contingent on facts.  You'll frequently see phrases like that stating: *It must have been true because...*

The two can overlap, but "had to be true" is more open to interpretation and has broader usage.